# Best way to kill ZK session correctly

Tags: servlet-filters, zk

I am using ZK framework on server. Also, I use Spring Security and home grown security server.
Session timeout in Servlet container - 3600 seconds.
Session timeout in security server - also 3600 seconds.
Sometimes security server's session fils, but ZK session is still alive. I wrote servlet filter to intercept requests and check security server's session for availability.

So, I can intercept request to `/zkau`, but it's POST request and during redirect ZK shows error message box, with message about server connection error.

Does anyone knows, is there any way to tell ZK that it's session needs to be destroyed?

Best regads and thanks for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you kill session immediately during *POST* request to */zkau*. Interface `org.zkoss.zk.ui.Session` has two methods to make session invalidated: `invalidate` and `invalidateNow`. The former method just sets the flag that indicates that session is invalid and native session will be invalidated on next request. I believe this is what you need.

Comment: Unfortumatelly, I can't get ZK session from servlet filter. `Executions.getCurrent().getSession()` returns null.

Comment: @gooamoko By default ZK uses session cache that just saves ZK session as an attribute of native session (see `org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SessionAgent` class for details). The following code snippet retrieves ZK session from the current servlet request or creates a new one: `WebManager.getSession(request.getServletContext(), (HttpServletRequest) request, false)`

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thanks for your answer.